# Prevent child div to fire events

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent the click event being fired when the user click the child or a div.

I have

```
<div class='test'>
   <div class='click1'>
     test 1

    </div>
   <div class='click1'>
     test 2

    </div>

   <div class='click1'>
     test 3

    </div>

</div>
```

my jquery

```
  $('.test').click(function(e){

      e.stopPropagation(); //doesn't work
     alert('click!')

  })
```

I need to register click event to the .test div and I don't want the alert pops when user clicks the child div.

Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
$('.test').click(function(e){
     if (e.target.className == 'click1') {
         return false;
     }
})
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/drDMK/

Or even this:

```
$('.test').click(function(e){
     if (e.target.className != 'test') {
         return false;
     }
})
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/drDMK/1/

Comment: This does not handle all child divs

Comment: It's not that hard to figure out how to accommodate for all but parent - see my update.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.test').on('click', '*', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rD2ua/

**EDIT**

```
$('.test').children().bind('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can just bind to children elements directly

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rD2ua/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help ahren, but my project used jquery 1.63 so 'on' won't work in my project. Any way out of this? +1 though

Comment: @FlyingCat - have updated, however, this will only affect direct descendants, not grandchildren etc. As a side note, I tried first with `.delegate()`, but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: +1 for .children().bind() best representing the requested operation without .on

Comment: What about children of children @Fresheyeball?

Comment: @AlienWebguy - In contradiction to my previous comment about it not working on grand-children... it should, considering the event would have to bubble through direct children element... at which point, event propagation would be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You should trap the click event at the child level (that is 'click1') and stop the propagation there. It is propagating UP to its parent ('test').